# -moz-calc crossbrowser (polyfills? hooks?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-calc

I'm working on some project currently in which I'm using LESS, CSS3 and some other "fancy" technologies. I have some piece of code which calculate height for me:

```
height: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
```

I also use -moz-calc in couple other places to calculate some stuff. The problem is to make it working crossbrowser (O, Safari, Chrome, IE8+). It's kinda tricky even when I try to do it via JS (jquery), but some cases are really tricky unfortunately. So I'm looking for some kind of bullet proof solution with automatic updates, just like it was CSS' calc().

Comment: Why are you unable to do this with LESS? "bullet proof solution" may not exist (certainly not in CSS), how are you attempting this with JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: @Madmartigan I can't run JS in my LESS file. dunno why. actually i can do something like this '@var: "hello".toUpperCase();' but this one '@height: document.body.clientHeight;' doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

http://caniuse.com/calc

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/calc

`-webkit-calc` (Available in the Chrome 19 Dev build, Should be available in the next Safari)

`calc` (IE9)

`---` (Opera does not support it yet)

Comment: _you can also use IE CSS Expressions for compatibility with older IE_ (trollface) But you shouldn't.

Comment: unfortunately -webkit-calc isn't supported yet. so calc() works only for IE9+, Firefox and that's it. This is why I'm looking for polyfills/hooks

Comment: ahh, .. true. But they are working on it. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16662 , - so your only solution now is JS, as it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Webkit just landed prefixed calc() support. -webkit-calc() currently works in the Chrome dev build and should be included in the next release of Chrome and Safari.